# changing font in middle of page

Tags: fonts

I wish to change the font type in the middle of a document. I ripped code from the LaTeX Wikibooks page to try and do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\renewcommand*
\rmdefault{ppl}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

but the font in the second paragraph remains the same. What is wrong, and how do I change it?

(Palintino font is installed. Motivation: in failing to find a document on the web that illustrated default LaTeX fonts, I wanted to create this myself. Yes, I am aware of the LaTeX font catalogue.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{ppl}
```

just sets the default family for font selections, it doesn't select a font.
Try using `\rmfamily` to select (the new) Roman family at any point after that.

Comment: Any chance you could have a full snippet of code, and an output please? I'm having tremendous difficulty trying to understand how to go about with this..... any help is much appreciated!

Comment: @3kstc the example is in the question, just add `\rmfamily`  before the second `\lipsum`